# Fly-out menu over iframe

Tags: jquery, css

I created a fly-out menu using `ul` tags ang jQuery. No problem there, however, a user wants to embed an iframe with a video player.

Unfortunately, the iframe always sits on top of the fly-out menus. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9GV7Y/3/

No matter what CSS tricks I try, the iframe refuses to comply.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** The fiddle works fine in Firefox, but not IE or Chrome.

Comment: It looks ok to me in firefox. The flyout menu is sitting above the iframe.

Comment: your fiddle works for me in FF

Comment: Interesting... but not IE/Chrome

Comment: The problem is not the iframe, but the flash object inside. If you hide the flash object the iframe is still there, and the menus are displayed correctly. Now, what can we do about that flash movie there?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have absolutely no control over the flash object as it is sourced from an external site. Javascript/jQuery won't even touch it as that would violate the "same origin" security policy. So, to answer you.... not much. :(

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the wmode attribute setted on the swf is transparent. That makes flash appear sometimes over all other elements (no matter what z-index elements have).

I've inspected your code, and found wmode=transparent in some places. Try replacing that wmode=transparent with wmode=opaque.

Comment: There was only one place where I append the url of the iframe `iframe.attr("src", url + "?wmode=transparent");`. If I change that to `iframe.attr("src", url + "?wmode=opaque");` it makes no difference.